# Change of Basis For Pauli Matrix From Z Diagonal to X Diagonal Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I want to find a matrix such that it takes a spin z ket in the z basis,

$$ \lvert S_z + \rangle_z  $$

and operates on it, giving me a spin z ket in the x basis,

$$  U \lvert S_z + \rangle_z =  \lvert S_z + \rangle_x $$

I would have thought that I could find this transformation operator matrix simply by using the following argument:

$$\begin{align}
U \lvert S_z \rangle_z &= \lvert S_z \rangle_x \\
{}_z\langle S_z  \rvert U \lvert S_z \rangle_z &= {}_z\langle S_z \rvert S_z \rangle_x
\end{align}$$

Therefore, elements of U are given by the inner product $${}_z\langle S_z \lvert S_z \rangle_x$$

However, to compute the inner product ${}_z\langle S_z \lvert S_z \rangle_x$, I need to know $\lvert S_z \rangle_x$, which is exactly what I am trying to find.

Where is my misunderstanding? Could you suggest what is incorrect with my transformation matrix $U$?

I have shown that the matrix given by the inner products ${}_z\langle S_z \lvert S_x \rangle_z$ gives the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}   1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}  \\   1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \end{pmatrix}

which cannot be correct, since ${}_z\langle S_z \lvert S_x \rangle_z \neq {}_z\langle S_z \lvert S_z \rangle_x$.

However, starting in the $x$ basis and calculating $\lvert S_z \rangle_x$ shows that the above matrix works. I imagine this is not a coincidence, but it seems to be implying that $$\lvert S_z \rangle_x = \lvert S_x + \rangle_z$$

Comment: Um...why do you think that changing the basis should change the vector? The vectors of a space *themselves* do not change when you change the basis, so a z-spin ket in one basis is a z-spin ket in all bases.

Comment: Hi bohrpi. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree - a change of basis should not change the vector. My question is why my transformation matrix U is incorrect. Editing question to make it clearer.